# Redireccion 301 url amigable

Tags: php, .htaccess

Cree una URL amigable así:

`RewriteRule ^productos Productos.php [NC,L]`

pero ahora quiero hacer una redirección 301 a `midominio.com/Productos.php` para que siempre que escriba `Productos.php` me redirija a `midominio.com/productos`

Comment: Buenas! Si ves que no encauzas nada por ese sitio utiliza javascript utiliza el comando "window.location=midominio.com/productos" y generará un desvio a la pagina web que quieras.

Comment: Tambien te recomiendo echarle un ojo al codigo 302 que es found y va acompañado de una cabecera location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En htaccess podrías hacerlo con Redirect, ten en cuenta que debe ir antes de al regla anterior para que productos pueda ser dirigido a Productos.php. Puedes ver más info [aqui](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess).

```
Redirect 301 /Productos.php /productos
```

Por otro lado, lo normal es que no se acceda por Productos.php porque todos los enlaces a tu página deberían llevar a productos.

También puedes hacerlo en php:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="Productos.php"){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: midominio.com/productos");
    header("Connection: close");
    exit;
}
```